# How do I only set the text to align-left if the phrase/sentence does not jump to next line?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on creating a banner that would get displayed only when needed. I am working on the design process and was wondering if there a technique i should to achieve the goal.

So I only need to align text as center if the phrase/sentence can fit as one sentence and does not jump onto next line? I set the attribute text-align as center, but when the text is long and jumps onto next line, then the text on line 2 get centered which I don't want to happen. So I was wondering if there was to achieve something like using `CSS` and `HTML`?

Just seeking for some ideas or tips.

[Here is the code](https://jsfiddle.net/3ktknpwb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the css property `white-space:nowrap` to make the div not wrap text initially.

Then, you can determine whether the text does wrap around using the `scrollWidth` and the `innerWidth` properties. You can use jquery to reset the `nowrap` property so that the element displays as you would want it to.

**CSS**

```
#innerNotification{
  font-family: Arial, Times New Roman;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #9F6000;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom:1%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**JS**

```
if ($('#innerNotification')[0].scrollWidth >  $('#innerNotification').innerWidth()) {
    $('#innerNotification').css('white-space','normal');
    $('#innerNotification').css('text-align','left');
}
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4hkxjy5/2/)

Comment: Thank you Neil. This helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries in CSS. You will just have to manually find the screen size that you would like to change the alignment.
An example is

```
#innerNotification{
     text-align:left;
}
@media screen and (min-width:700px){ //pick the correct screen width here
 #innerNotification{
     text-align:center;
 }
}
```

The is a lot of information on media queries here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Thank you Tofu! This helps.